# JQuery-UI dialog widget and Fine-Uploader Upload

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, fine-uploader

I have this problem when I am trying to make an upload. The url configured in the request endpoint for the FineUploader instance is not reached.
I am using FineUploader v3.7.1 and JQuery-UI v1.10.3. 
Below is my code:

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                height: 500,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "Aceptar",
                        click: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });

        $('#upload').fineUploader({
            text: {
                uploadButton: 'Agregar imágen al evento',
                deleteButton: 'Eliminar imagen'
            },
            // template for one item in file list
            fileTemplate:
                '<span>' +
                '<div class="qq-progress-bar"></div>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-finished"></span>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-file"></span>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-size"></span>' +
                '<a class="qq-upload-cancel" href="#">{cancelButtonText}</a>' +
                '<a class="qq-upload-retry" href="#">{retryButtonText}</a>' +
                '<a class="qq-upload-delete" href="#">{deleteButtonText}</a>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-status-text">{statusText}</span>' +
                '</span>',
            classes: {
            },
            request: {
                endpoint: '<%= Url.Action("UploadNewDesign", "Account") %>'
            },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                endpoint: '<%= Url.Action("DeleteNewDesign", "Account") %>',
                method: 'POST'
            },
            multiple: true,
            validation: {

            },
            showMessage: function (message) {

            },
            messages: {

            }
        })
        .on('submit', function (event, id, name) {

        })
        .on('submitted', function (event, id, name) {
            var fileItemContainer = $(this).fineUploader('getItemByFileId', id);

            $('#dialog').html(fileItemContainer);
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        })
        .on('complete', function (event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
            if (responseJSON.success) {

            }
        })
        .on('submitDelete', function (event, id) {

        })
        .on('deleteComplete', function (event, id, xhrOrXdr, isError) {
            if (!isError) {

            }
        });
    })
```

HTML

```
<div id="upload"></div>
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

This only happens when I put the fileTemplate html (Calling the FineUploader API) on a JQuery Dialog Widget. If I try to put the fileTemplate html in an element inside the view, the Action Controller is reached.

**UPDATE**

Below if my Updated code, I was duplicating the DOM of the fileTemplate

SCRIPT

```
$('#upload').fineUploader({
            text: {
                uploadButton: 'Agregar imágen al evento',
                deleteButton: 'Eliminar imagen'
            },
            listElement: $('#dialog')[0],
            fileTemplate:
                '<span>' +
                '<div class="qq-progress-bar"></div>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-finished"></span>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-file"></span>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-size"></span>' +
                '<a class="qq-upload-cancel" href="#">{cancelButtonText}</a>' +
                '<a class="qq-upload-retry" href="#">{retryButtonText}</a>' +
                '<a class="qq-upload-delete" href="#">{deleteButtonText}</a>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-status-text">{statusText}</span>' +
                '</span>',
            classes: {
            },
            request: {
                endpoint: '<%= Url.Action("UploadNewDesign", "Account") %>'
            },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                endpoint: '<%= Url.Action("DeleteNewDesign", "Account") %>',
                method: 'POST'
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['png'],
                sizeLimit: 411062 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
            },
            multiple: true,
            showMessage: function (message) {
                $('#dialog').html(message);
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            },
            messages: {

            }
        })
        .on('submit', function (event, id, name) {

        })
        .on('submitted', function (event, id, name) {
            var fileItemContainer = $(this).fineUploader('getItemByFileId', id);

            $('#dialog').html(fileItemContainer);
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        })
        .on('complete', function (event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
            if (responseJSON.success) {
                var fileName = $(this).fineUploader('getName', id);
                $('#tblFiles > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + fileName + '</td></tr>');
            }
        })
        .on('submitDelete', function (event, id) {

        })
        .on('deleteComplete', function (event, id, xhrOrXdr, isError) {
            if (!isError) {

            }
        });
    })
```

HTML

```
<div id="upload"></div>
<div id="dialog"></div>

<table id="tblFiles">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

I successfully do what I am trying to do. Please take a look and tell me if it is a better way of doing what I do. Below there are some images (OHH STACKOVERFLOW doesn´t allow me because I don´t have enough reputation, I ended deleting all of it), explaining what I was searching

Finally the code Updated, please let me know if it is a better way

```
$('#FileTemplate').dialog({
            //dialogClass: "no-dialog-titlebar-close",
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            height: "auto",
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Aceptar",
                    click: function () {

                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();

        $('#Messages').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: "auto",
            height: "auto",
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Aceptar",
                    click: function () {

                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ]
        }); 

        $('#Upload').fineUploader({
            messages: {
                typeError: "{file} tiene una extension inválida. Las extensiones validas son: {extensions}.",
                sizeError: "{file} is too large, maximum file size is {sizeLimit}.",
                minSizeError: "{file} is too small, minimum file size is {minSizeLimit}.",
                emptyError: "{file} is empty, please select files again without it.",
                noFilesError: "No files to upload.",
                tooManyItemsError: "Too many items ({netItems}) would be uploaded.  Item limit is {itemLimit}.",
                retryFailTooManyItems: "Retry failed - you have reached your file limit.",
                onLeave: "The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be cancelled."
            },
            text: {
                uploadButton: 'Agregar imágen al evento',
                deleteButton: 'Eliminar imagen',
                cancelButton: 'Cancel',
                retryButton: 'Retry',
                failUpload: 'Upload failed',
                formatProgress: "{percent}% de {total_size}",
                waitingForResponse: "Procesando..."
            },
            template: '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
                '<div class="qq-upload-drop-area"><span>{dragZoneText}</span></div>' +
                '<div class="div-button-style"><div>{uploadButtonText}</div></div>' +
                '<span class="qq-drop-processing"><span>{dropProcessingText}</span><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>' +
                '</div>',
            listElement: $("#FileTemplate"),
            fileTemplate:
                '<span>' +
                    '<div class="qq-progress-bar"></div>' +
                    '<span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span>' +
                    '<span class="qq-upload-finished"></span>' +
                    '<span class="qq-upload-file"></span>' +
                    '<span class="qq-upload-size"></span>' +
                    '<a class="qq-upload-cancel" href="#">{cancelButtonText}</a>' +
                    '<a class="qq-upload-retry" href="#">{retryButtonText}</a>' +
                    '<a class="qq-upload-delete-hide" href="#">{deleteButtonText}</a>' +
                    '<span class="qq-upload-status-text">{statusText}</span>' +
                '</span>',
            classes: {
                deleteButton: "qq-upload-delete-hide",
                button: "div-button-style"
            },
            request: {
                endpoint: '<%= Url.Action("UploadNewDesign", "Account") %>'
            },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                endpoint: '<%= Url.Action("DeleteNewDesign", "Account") %>',
                method: 'POST'
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['png'],
                sizeLimit: 411062 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
            },
            multiple: true,
            showMessage: function (message) {
                $('#Messages').html(message);
                $("#Messages").dialog("open");
            }
        })
        .on('submitted', function (event, id, name) {

            var files = $('#Upload').fineUploader('getUploads');
            // SPECIALLY IN THIS PART, WHERE I'M HIDING ALL THE OTHERS FILETEMPLATES
            $.each(files, function (index, value) {
                var exists = $('#Upload').fineUploader('doesExist', value.id);

                if (exists && value.id != id)
                    $('#Upload').fineUploader('getItemByFileId', value.id).hide(); 
            });

            $("#FileTemplate").dialog("open");
        })
        .on('complete', function (event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
            if (responseJSON.success) {
                var fileName = $(this).fineUploader('getName', id);
                $('#tblFiles > tbody:last').append(
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td class="hide-element"><input type="hidden" value="' + responseJSON.filename + '"/></td>' +
                        '<td class="hide-element"><input type="hidden" value="' + id + '"/></td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                            '<div class="pointer-cursor" title="Eliminar imagen" onclick="DeleteImage(' + id + ')">' +
                                '<image src="/Images/trash.png" />' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td onclick="SelectImage(' + id + ')" class="pointer-cursor">' + fileName + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>');

                SelectImage(id);

                return;
            }

            $('#Messages').html("Se produjo un error al subir el archivo");
            $("#Messages").dialog("open");
        })
        .on('submitDelete', function (event, id) {
            $(this).fineUploader('setDeleteFileParams', { filename: $(this).fineUploader('getName', id)}, id);
        })
        .on('deleteComplete', function (event, id, xhrOrXdr, isError) {
            if (!isError) {

                var trIndex;
                var trRemoved = false;
                var firstFileId;

                for (trIndex = 0; trIndex < $('#tblFiles tbody tr').length && !trRemoved; trIndex++) {
                    var fileId = $($('#tblFiles tbody tr')[trIndex]).find('td input')[1].value;

                    if (!firstFileId)
                        firstFileId = fileId;

                    // Remove the tr associated with file
                    if (fileId == id) {
                        $($('#tblFiles tbody tr')[trIndex]).remove();
                        trRemoved = true;
                    }
                }

                if ($('#tblFiles tbody tr').length == 0) {
                    // No images left
                    $("#imgUploaded").attr("src", "/Images/no_image_mid.png");
                    $("#IdImageSelected").val("");
                }
                else {
                    // If the image was the selected, selected another
                    if ($("#IdImageSelected").val() == id)
                        SelectImage(firstFileId);
                }

                return;
            }

            $('#Messages').html("Se produjo un error al querer eliminar el archivo");
            $("#Messages").dialog("open");
        });

    })

    function DeleteImage(id) {
        $('#Upload').fineUploader('deleteFile', id);
    }

    function SelectImage(id) {

        $('#tblFiles tbody tr').each(function () {

            var fileId = $(this).find('td input')[1].value;
            // FileName on server
            var fileName = $(this).find('td input')[0].value;

            var row = $(this).children();

            if (fileId == id) {
                // Assign the selected style
                row.addClass("image-selected");

                $("#imgUploaded").attr("src", "<%: _imagesDirectory %>/" + fileName);
                $("#IdImageSelected").val(id);
            }
            else {
                row.removeClass("image-selected");
            }
        });
    }
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img id="imgUploaded" src="/Images/no_image_mid.png"  style="width:200px; height:200px" />
                <input type="hidden" class="hide-element" id="IdImageSelected"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="Upload"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="FileTemplate"></div>
<div id="Messages" title="Error"></div>

<table id="tblFiles">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I hope you understand what I am trying to do

Comment: What do you mean it's "not reached"?  Please provide more specific information regarding your issue.  Is the request being sent?  If not, how do you know?  Are you seeing any errors in the javascript console? etc

Comment: I am using Fiddler, to analize requests. When I put the FileTemplate html returned from the api "getItemByFileId" in the onSubmitted callback on the Dialog Widget, I cannot see a request to the URL specified in the request endpoint on Fiddler. Is like FineUploader was set with autoupload in false. I hope this helps.

Comment: Can I ask exactly what you are trying to do?  After your comment, I just noticed that you are taking the DOM element associated with the file that Fine Uploader UI creates, duplicating it, and pasting it elsewhere.  Do you have a link to your live app, so I can take a closer look?

Comment: Ray, I don't have a link to the WebSite it's under construction. If everything goes fine, you will going to have a purchased license of FineUploader for me before my WebSite goes live. I found the solution, only reading this "I just noticed that you are taking the DOM element associated with the file that Fine Uploader UI creates, duplicating it, and pasting it elsewhere". What I am trying to do is to put all messages and fileTemplate in a PopUp, then all The Net files Uploaded name are going to be on a table. I put my Updated code, to let you see if everything is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still a little confused by your code.  I'll do my best to answer your question, but it would be make it much easier for me to help you if you would simply provide a link to a page that contains a working version of the code you have listed in your question.

Fine Uploader will create the file items inside of your #dialog, since you have set #dialog as your `listElement`.  This seems like what you want to do, based on your comments.  But, you are replacing the entire contents of #dialog every time a file is submitted in your `submitted` handler.  Why?  I'm guessing you really don't want to do this.  You should take another look at the [documentation for jQuery's `html` function](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

You are also overwriting the contents (again) of this same #dialog with messages from Fine Uploader in your `showMessage` implementation.  Again, I'm sure you also don't want to do this.  If you want to display these messages in a custom dialog, fine, but you should choose a NEW dialog, not the same one holding the HTML for the uploader.

All I can suggest is that you should remove your `submitted` handler and your `showMessage` implementations, as the code you have added to these two sections doesn't make any sense.

Also, you have a bunch of empty options.  I'm not sure if you don't understand how those work, if you just have left out portions of your code for some reason.

Finally, you can pass in the jQuery object for your #dialog, since you are using the Fine Uploader jQuery wrapper.  Your `listElement` option can have a value of `$('dialog')`.

Comment: Ray, some options was empty because, I was writing the code. There wasn´t important parts to achieve my goal. I make and update of the code. I was taking the job of do some pictures to explain better, but I don't have reputation. The updated code has the messages in another upload and none html was overwrited. Again let me know if its a better way of doing what I am trying to do, because I like to learn.